# Openpyxl & Python - Combining data from cells in two columns into a single column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet with data on people, in which first names are in cells in column L and last names are in the cells in column M. I need to combine these into variables that contain both the first and last name for each person.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/userName/Desktop/sheetName.xlsx')
main = wb['Sheet1']
```

The following code will do this for a single row, but I need to make it iterate through every row containing data.

```
cell1 = main['L1'].value
cell2 = main['M1'].value
cell3 = cell1+cell2
print(cell3)
```

Here is what I'm trying, but I keep getting the error message *name 'rows' is not defined*

```
combined = []
for i in main.rows:
    combined.append(i.value for i in row)
print(combined)
```

Thanks in advance for help with this puzzle!

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Be careful with that loop, take a look at which variables you're defining, and where.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got working:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/userName/Desktop/testSheet.xlsx')
main = wb['Sheet1']

for row in range(2, main.max_row +1):
    firstName = main["L" + str(row)].value
    lastName = main["M" + str(row)].value
    fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName
    print(fullName)
```